# how can i type this axios request function properly and make it reusable using typescript

Tags: typescript, axios, typescript-generics, code-reuse

The purpose of the code below is to be resuable across projects maybe with slight modifications

- The OnSuccess function handles the AxiosResponse
- The OnError function handles the AxiosError

How can I define types for the data I'm getting from an api and use it to type the AxiosResponse in OnSuccess function and maybe other improvements like e.g the bearer token etc.
**Forgive me! I'm just an newbie**

> Here is the code below

```
import axios from 'axios';

const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:5500/',
});

export const request = ({ ...options }) => {
  client.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer Token`;
  const onSuccess = (response) => response;
  const onError = (error) => {
    // optionally catch errors and add additional logging here
    // maybe redirect to login page to auth error
    return error;
  };

  return client(options).then(onSuccess).catch(onError);
};

export default client;
```

**Calling Functions**

```
const fetchSuperHeroes = () => {
  // return client.get('superheroes');
  return client({ url: '/superheroes' });
};

// OR
const addSuperHero = (hero) => {
  // return client.post('superheroes', hero);
  return client({ url: '/superheroes', method: 'post', data: hero });
};
// OR

const fetchSuperHero = ({ queryKey }) => {
  const heroId = queryKey[1];
  return client.get(`superheroes/${heroId}`);
};
```

**Usage**

```
  const { data, error } = useQuery('super-heroes', fetchSuperHeroes);
```

**PS**
Ignore the querykey param in the last example usage function: it's just react-query syntax